# git push success but returns error message

Tags: gitlab, tortoisegit

There,
when I use git to push my code to *gitlab*, it actually succeeds and I can see my renewed code from *gitlab* web interface.

However it keeps returning an error message: *"No supported authentication
methods availabe(server sent:publickey, keyboard-interactive)"*.
I don't understand this.

I have another project hosted by gitlab also. I don't have any problem on pushing code
from this project. I wonder what could happen to the first project.

Please clarify me from this mess.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: I have figured this out myself (with a bit imply from Tux) . I used the default commands from gitlab website to build a new project, which I hadn't brought in a ssh key. I deleted the files in my disk and cloned another project with ssh-key enabled, and it worked. Thanks to MrTux.

Comment: Please accept the answer to say thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeming to use a git URL for pushing/pulling.

In order to get this working you need to load your PuTTY key into the PuTTY agent (pageant; TortoiseGit usually does this automnatically if you have configured a PuTTY key for a remote).

Another way is to configure a PuTTY session (or modify the default session), cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-faq.html#tgit-ssh-faq-defaultkey and https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html.

A third way could be to switch to a https URL for remote operations.